# Big spike of 6000+ ms caused by Font.CacheFontForText

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, fonts, rendering

I'm creating a game with Unity and on loading the first scene I get a 6000+ ms spike caused by Font.CacheFontForText and I think it is because all my texts in the scene have Best Fit checked (because as far as I know is the best method to scale texts over different screen sizes automatically), I searched for this problem, but from what I understood I have to pre popolate all the texts in my scene, and they are a lot. Can I avoid to do this and resolve this problem in another way? I ran the profiler on the editor and on Android and the spikes shows up only on Android? Why it works fine in the editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BestFit tries all the font sizes one by one, to find the biggest one to fit in the Text RectTransform. This way it will be really slow if you have multiple Texts with BestFit in the scene. It allocates a drawcall for each size as well, so using BestFit is usually a bad practice. Try having different font size for different resolutions and only set the font size on Start() function. Example:

```
public int[] widths;
public int[] textSizes;
public Text[] texts;
private int widthIndex;

void Start()
{
    for(int i = widths.Length - 1; i >= 0; i++) {
        if(Screen.width > widths[i]) {
            widthIndex = i;
            break;
        }
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < texts.Length; i++) {
        texts[i].textSize = textSizes[widthIndex];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But I have to execute this for every text that has a different text size, right? For example one time for the texts that needs to get smaller ( a smaller text size for a screen size ) and one time for the bigger texts ( a bigger text size for the same screen size), hope to have explained myself well!

Comment: That was just an example. The point is not to use the Best Fit if you have lot of Texts. You will need to find the best way that suits your project.